# Узнать количество n угольников в блендере

Tags: 3d, blender

Недавно начала изучать как работать в блендере, и возникла острая нужда узнать количество n угольников в модельке в блендере, где n >= 5. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjsRTGw9yms

Answer (score 0):

Найти можно с помощью select - Select all by Trait - Faces by sides.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]